# The screen quality on my brand new TV is messed up when i use it as monitor for my pc (HDMI). It's fuzzy and blurry

Tags: display, resolution, tv

Not just text, everything is a little blurry. My PC didn't have an issue with previous monitors and this TV is brand new, just unboxed.

- The resolution and scaling is set right
- In the TV screen settings 'PC Mode' is turned on
- I downloaded the latest drivers for my NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1080 videocard
- I tried ClearType tuner
- I unchecked "Smooth edges of Screen Font" and "Use drop shadows for icons on the desktop"

Any suggestions?

Comment: How's the TV connected?

Comment: What's the resolution of the TV? What was the resolution of your last monitor? What are the dimensions of each? How are/were they connected?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: "The resolution and scaling is set right" probably not, otherwise it wouldn't be blurry. Disconnect between physical TV resolution and the one you can select? (Some TVs allow higher "virtual" resolution than the physical one). Is there some "overscan compensation" setting somewhere that indirectly affects resolution? Interlace somewhere? Or potential filters (often hide under "user friendly" names in the TV UI)? Anyhow, it's impossible to say anything without at least brand name of TV and/or link to manual of the TV.